# One of my CSS classes is not having any effect

Tags: html, css

I have two headers, one with `class="mainHeader"`, and another with `class="subHeader"`. I'm trying to contain both of those in another class by using `<div class="header">` beforehand (and a `</div>` after of course). However in my CSS file that I linked, when I try to do `.header { /* styling */ }`, no matter what I put in there nothing changes when I open the HTML file.

Here are my files:

```css
<!DOCTYPE css>

.header {
  font-family: Roboto, serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: Black;
}

.mainHeader {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.subHeader {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 0em;
  word-spacing: 0.25em;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <link href="WSDS-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Temp title</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="header">
   <h1 class="mainHeader">Temp main heading</h1>
   <h2 class="subHeader">Temp sub-heading</h2>
 </div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

As you can see when you run it, no styling made in the ".header" is used. I'm still pretty new to this so please understand if it's an easy fix!

Comment: Remove <!DOCTYPE css> and it should work.

Comment: You might also want to verify that the stylesheet is linked to the correct path.

Comment: Well yup, that was the problem, I officially feel like an idiot. Gotta learn somehow right haha. Anyway thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't define a doctype for CSS files, remove `<!DOCTYPE css>`.

```css
.header {
  font-family: Roboto, serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: Black;
}

.mainHeader {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.subHeader {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 0em;
  word-spacing: 0.25em;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="WSDS-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Temp title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="mainHeader">Temp main heading</h1>
    <h2 class="subHeader">Temp sub-heading</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- DOCTYPE declarations are for HTML based documents.So remove `<!DOCTYPE css>` from   your css file.
- Make sure file path for css file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<!DOCTYPE css>` from your css file. DOCTYPE declarations are for HTML based documents.